# How to Join Multiple Joins yet return Distinct Values

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to Join Multiple Tables.
Table 1 has distinct ID's
Table 2 has multiple names for each ID SAY 3 NAMES
Table 3 has 2 dates for each ID

when i join the Three tables, I get 6 rows of data for each ID with each of the Names appearing Twice and each of the dates appearing thrice.

I want only 3 rows to be written returning distinct 3 names and Distinct 2 dates for each ID. Is there any way to do this while using Joins in SQL?

Answer (score 2):

To get one result row per row in table 1, you have to use a grouping function on the other tables. For example, if you want the last (in ascending sort order) name and date, you'd use

```
select t1.id,
       max(t2.name),
       max(t3.datefield)
  from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
  join table3 t3 on t3.id = t1.id
 group by t1.id
;
```

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this which doesn't use explicit `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT T1.ID
  FROM Table1 AS T1
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT * 
                 FROM Table2 AS T2
                WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID
              )
       AND EXISTS (
                   SELECT * 
                     FROM Table3 AS T3
                    WHERE T3.ID = T1.ID
                  );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you preface your query with SELECT DISTINCT, you should return only the distinct rows.

Comment: That will give you the distinct rows, but every row is unique because of the combination of name and date, so I don't think that's what he actually wants.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you'll want to use the GROUP BY clause

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 0):

You really need to understand what it is you are trying to return and why.

Please post your example source rows and the results you want to achieve (and why).

The reason you get 6 rows is because there are 6 possibilities which match your model as you have stated it.

If this is "too many", you need to add an additional criteria, as yet unstated, that determines **which** date is the one you wish to display with each name.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to do two queries.

```
SELECT id, name FROM names WHERE id = 1
SELECT id, date FROM dates WHERE id = 1
```

The type of operation that it sounds like you are trying to do isn't really valid since the results wouldn't really be a relation. (you'd have one column with 3 rows and one column with 2 rows)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I am trying to do

Table1
ID
401

Table 2
ID    NameType     Name
401    Primary      Anu1
401    AKA          Anu2
401    Maiden       Anu3

Table 3
ID     DateType   Date
401     DOB        1983-09-25
401     DOD        2008-05-07

I write my join like
Select a.ID,b.NameType,b.Name,c.datetype,c.date
FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN Table2 b ON a.ID=b.ID
LEFT JOIN Table3 c ON a.ID=c.ID

This returns me
ID   NameType   Name   Datetype   Date
401   Primary   Anu1    DOB       1983-09-25
401   Primary   Anu1    DOD       2008-05-07
401   AKA       Anu2    DOB       1983-09-25
401   AKA       Anu2    DOD       2008-05-07
401   Maiden    Anu3    DOB       1983-09-25
401   Maiden    Anu3    DOD       2008-05-07

Is it possible to get the results like this:

ID   NameType  Name   Datetype  Date
401  Primary   Anu1    DOB       1983-09-25
401  AKA       Anu2    DOD       2008-05-07
401  Maiden    Anu3

Or else in any other way so that the same Names or Dates are not repeated multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide what one record you want from each table and join so that only that record joins to it. The way you are displaying data you cannot do all on one line because the information is differnt in the joining tables, so you must determine what the business rule is for choosing which of the multiple records you want.

NOw if you want the primary name and both the DOb and the DOD, this is what I would do:
Select a.ID,b.NameType,b.Name,c.date as DOB, d.date as DOD 
FROM Table1 a 
LEFT JOIN Table2 b ON a.ID=b.ID and b.name_type = 'Primary'
LEFT JOIN Table3 c ON a.ID=c.ID and c.datetype= 'DOB'
LEFT JOIN Table3 d ON a.ID=d.ID and d.datetype= 'DOD'

Now you could do the same with multiple joins for the other names, but you probably don't know how many joins you would want in advance. Theres a solution for that too but it is more complicated and I don't have time to get it for you, but basically you have to create a process to concatenate all the namess together in a temp table of some sort (which also has the id) and then join to that temp table.